# Android XML problems

Tags: android, xml

I am COMPLETELY NEW to xml... I was wondering, what is the best guide to read up with... Also, if the tutorial had stuff on formatting, as in.... well I am trying to make this... (NOTE they are buttons)

[image]

Sorry for asking what I know is a stupid question.. I'm just horrible at self teaching, so a helping direction to the guides I should read for making XML UI would be VERY appreciated

Comment: you can learn the simple layout designing in xml for android apps development from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android layout check out
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

The guys over here usually got pretty good tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp
This should help you become familiar with Xml before you continue with Android.

Comment: I think he is asking for XML file tutorial which he could write in Android layout designing. And not just credating simple Xml file.

Comment: However as he is completely new to xml jumping into layouts right away might be confusing since they don't bother explaining xml itself.

Answer (score 0):

For basic introduction to designing a layout, the developer tutorials on the android developer website should be good enough. You do not need to know anything about xml in order to learn about designing a layout. If xml proves to be such a big headache, you can always use the graphic tool to place buttons on the UI. The xml code will be generated automatically. You can find this feature in Eclipse IDE in the tab right next to the xml file where it is displayed.